# How to Query or Command to check "Running Packages" on Integration Services

Tags: sql-server, ssis

When we open SQL Server Integration Services object type in SSMS, we can see what packages are run either by agent or manually by visual studio.

How we can make query or run command to make result like this

[image]

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking here. Are you asking how to write a SQL query to get a list of the packages on the server? That looks like you're using the old MSDB deployment, which you can't query from SQL Server. How comes you haven't migrated to the SSISDB model?

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-retrieve-information-about-ssis-packages-stored-in-msdb-database/